# Database Dependency Chart?

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, oracle-12c, database-diagrams, dependencies

I have several SQL Server (2008 forward) and Oracle (12c forward) legacy databases running on a server... I know for a fact that various stored procedures point to other databases, like `select * from OtherDB.mySchema.Products`, which makes a database dependent on `OtherDB`...

Is there a easy way to map this "interdependencies", ideally generating a chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers will vary for SQL Server vs Oracle.

For SQL Server, you can [view dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/view-the-dependencies-of-a-table?view=sql-server-ver16) of an object two ways:

1. You can use SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) and right click on the object. Then click on View Dependencies:

[image: SSMS - View Dependencies]

2. You can use the following T-SQL (from the previously linked docs) to query the `sys.sql_expression_dependencies` system view:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies  
WHERE referencing_id = OBJECT_ID(N'SchemaName.ObjectName');
```